# Kotlin recyclerView doesn't call any Adapter method

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

RecyclerView adapter make me sick - there is no any call of adapter's methods during app run. Data was initialized in FileListPresenterImpl class, but no any call. Please, help.

```
class FileListAdapter(val fileList: List<File>):
        RecyclerView.Adapter<FileListAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int)  {
        holder.bindData(fileList[position])
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        var v = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.row_item_file, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = fileList.size

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bindData(file: File) {
            itemView.tvFileName.text = file.getFileName()
            itemView.tvPath.text = file.savePath
        }
    }
}


class FileListFragment: ListFragment(), FileListView, ListFragment.RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener {

    lateinit private var addFileDialog: AddFileDialogFragment
    lateinit private var listAdapter: FileListAdapter
    lateinit private var listData: ArrayList<File>

    val presenter = FileListPresenterImpl(this)

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        return context.inflateLayout(R.layout.fragment_list)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        addFileDialog = AddFileDialogFragment()

        rvDataList.addOnItemTouchListener(object : RecyclerItemClickListener(activity, listener = this) {})
        presenter.loadFileList()

        fab.setOnClickListener { showNewFileAddDialog() }

    }

    ...

    override fun onFileListLoad(fileList: ArrayList<File>) {
        listData = fileList
        initAdapter()
    }

    private fun initAdapter() {
        listAdapter = FileListAdapter(listData)
        rvDataList.adapter = listAdapter
    }


}


class FileListPresenterImpl(private val view: FileListView): FileListPresenter {

    override fun loadFileList() {
        //TODO load fileList from DB
        view.onFileListLoad(loadTestFileList())
    }

    ...

    private fun loadTestFileList(): ArrayList<File> {
        var testData = ArrayList<File>()

        var downloadFolder : String = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS

        val f: File = File(downloadFolder, "http://cdndl.zaycev.net/154044/4082702/vremya_i_steklo_-_navernopotomuchto_(zaycev.net).mp3")

        testData.add(File(downloadFolder, "http://cdndl.zaycev.net/154044/4082702/vremya_i_steklo_-_navernopotomuchto_(zaycev.net).mp3"))
        testData.add(File(downloadFolder, "http://cdndl.zaycev.net/871888/4212215/craig_david_and_sigala_-_ain_t_giving_up_(zaycev.net).mp3"))
        testData.add(File(downloadFolder, "http://cdndl.zaycev.net/111639/4135024/albina_-_ne_nado_(zaycev.net).mp3"))
        testData.add(File(downloadFolder, "http://cdndl.zaycev.net/126287/4087650/pika_-_patimeyker_(zaycev.net).mp3"))
        testData.add(File(downloadFolder, "http://cdndl.zaycev.net/861221/4125726/lil_wayne_and_wiz_khalifa_and_imagine_dragons_and_logic_and_ty_dolla_sign_and_x_ambassadors_-_sucker_for_pain_(zaycev.net).mp3"))
        testData.add(File(downloadFolder, "http://cdndl.zaycev.net/12757/4212221/the_black_eyed_peas_-_where_is_the_love_2016_remake_(zaycev.net).mp3"))
        testData.add(File(downloadFolder, "http://cdndl.zaycev.net/118309/4214105/yolka_-_na_bolshom_vozdushnom_share_(zaycev.net).mp3"))
        testData.add(File(downloadFolder, "http://cdndl.zaycev.net/126708/3989697/potap_i_nastya_-_umamy_(zaycev.net).mp3"))
        testData.add(File(downloadFolder, "http://cdndl.zaycev.net/871784/4211700/philip_rossa_-_pam_pam_pam..._radio_edit_(zaycev.net).mp3"))
        testData.add(File(downloadFolder, "http://cdndl.zaycev.net/123704/4087949/mot_-_na_dne_(zaycev.net).mp3"))

        return testData
    }

}
```

https://github.com/AntonKostyukewicz/Downloader - sources

Comment: Please add the part of the code that instantiates `FileListAdapter` and attaches it to the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Since you solve problem, please select your answer as solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is solved. I missed setting of LayoutManager to recyclerView